# Django: Sessions not working as expected on Heroku

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, redis

Users keep getting logged out and sessions are not persisting on my Django app on Heroku. Users can log in, but they will be randomly logged out—even on the `/admin/` site.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with my Django/Heroku config?

Currently running Django 1.11.16 on Standard Dynos.

**settings.py**

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", "".join(random.choice(string.printable) for i in range(40)))

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".appname.com"
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".appname.com"

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

# ...

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'appname',
    }
}

# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Comment: Which backend are you using to store your session data? Are you running on multiple dynos?

Comment: What are your DATABASES settings?

Comment: Added DATABASES settings above. It's hooked up on Heroku Config with DATABASE_URL=postgres://...

Comment: @Chris Running with the default SESSION_ENGINE on Standard Dynos

Comment: What about the session key. Is the same all time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that `SECRET_KEY` was not static on Heroku. The `SECRET_KEY` changing was breaking sessions. The fix is to add a static `SECRET_KEY` to Heroku config:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=`openssl rand -base64 32`
```

Comment: FYI, if you don't want to do that, you might consider instead using localstorage on the browser combined with itsdangerous (the Python library) to validate the content. That way you won't be storing sessions server-side, which can be problematic for a lot of reasons.